# Floated Image won't float to the proper space. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css, image, html-lists

I'm trying to float an image to the right of an unordered list using `float: left`, but the picture stays stubbornly underneath the `div` with the `ul`.

I've tried `display: inline-block, I've  tried making them all block level elements, and I've messed with the margins and padding on both but the more I mess with the margins the less the code looks like the blueprint I've been given. Perhaps I don't fully grasp how floats work exactly.

Why won't the image float to the right of the `div` with the list?

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<div id="introText" class="margins">
        <p>Now you can get the digital sound quality you want at an affordable price. With more than 50 years of microphone innovation, Sony introduces the new UWP-D wireless microphone system. Just because your project is budget-driven doesn't mean you have to compromise on sound quality.</p>
        <p>Sony's new wireless mics are the ideal audio-for-video solution that will boost the performance of even entry-level camcorders. Choose from among three packages, any of which are well-suited for ENG and field production or any budget-conscious application requiring high-quality digital audio.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="listWrap benefitsList">
        <div class="inLine">
            <div class="heading">
                <p id="listHeading" class="margins">Key Benefits:</p>
            </div>
            <ul class="ulBenefits">
                <li><p>Wide range with up to 72 channels</p></li>
                <li><p>Three separate UHF frequency blocks available</p></li>
                <li><p>USB Portable Charger w/Lithium-Ion Battery and AC adapter</p></li>
                <li><p>Sturdy metal body construction</li>
                <li><p>Digital audio processing</li>
                <li><p>A DSP compander provides superb transient response performance</p></li>
                <li><p>Wide switching RF bandwidth with 3 UHF frequency blocks available</p></li>
                <li><p>True diversity receiver for stable reception</p></li>
                <li><p>Output audio gain control on receiver</p></li>
                <li><p>Headphone output on receiver</p></li>
                <li><p>Handheld TX includes interchangeable capsule design</p></li>
                <li><p>Mic or line input on both body-pack and plug-on transmitters</p></li>
                <li><p>Sony UWP/800 Series &amp; Legacy Analog Wireless System compatibility</p></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="inLine cameraDiv">
            <img id="camera" alt="Camera" src="images/camera.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearIt blockIt">
        <img id="headingTwo" alt="Digital Sound Innovation for Analog Systems" src="images/headerTwo.jpg" />
    </div>
```

And here's the relevant CSS:

```
#listHeading {
    background: #eceeef;
    margin: 6px 13px;
}

#camera {
    width: 354px;
    height: 380px;
}

.inLine {
    display: inline-block;
}

#camera, .listWrap {
    display: inline-block;
}

.listWrap {
    margin-left: 1px;
}

.benefitsList {
    width: 422px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.cameraDiv {
    width: 354px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.heading {
    margin-left: 25px;
    width: 422px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #eceeef;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.heading #listHeading{
    margin-top: 4px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    background: #eceeef;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.ulBenefits {
    padding-left: 20px;
}


.ulBenefits li{
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eceeef;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    list-style-type: disc;
    padding: 0;
}

.ulBenefits li p{
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#headingTwo {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

The problem is the "camera.jpg" image. It always appears on the next line. Any ideas? Thanks in advance! Here's a fiddle of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/S3523/

The camera image SHOULD be to the right of and on the same line as the unordered list above it. But instead it returns to the next line.

Comment: Please, add a JSFiddle of your problem and maybe a mockup of desired result. It seems a simple problem, we need just to understand what exactly do you want :-)

Comment: I posted a fiddle and an explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're specifying a fixed width for the parent .benefitsList element so the image has no space to actually float to the left of the child list. So I removed the width on .benefitsList, floated .inLine left and it works.

Here's the CSS

```
<style>

.landingWrapper{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14;
    width: 784px;
    display: block;
}

.blockIt {
    display: block;
}

.clearIt {
    clear: both;
    min-height: 50px;
}
.margins {
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-right: 35px;
}

.introText {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#listHeading {
    background: #eceeef;
    margin: 6px 13px;
}

#camera {
    width: 354px;
    height: 380px;
}

.inLine {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}

#camera, .listWrap {
    display: inline-block;
}

.listWrap {
    margin-left: 1px;
}

.benefitsList {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.cameraDiv {
    width: 354px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.heading {
    margin-left: 25px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #eceeef;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.heading #listHeading{
    margin-top: 4px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    background: #eceeef;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.ulBenefits {
    padding-left: 20px;
}


.ulBenefits li{
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eceeef;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    list-style-type: disc;
    padding: 0;
}

.ulBenefits li p{
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#headingTwo {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#secondaryText {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    width: 714px;
}


.diagrams{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    min-height: 50px;
    width: 713px;
    height: 195px;
}


.infoBox{
    border: 1px solid #eceeef;
    border-top: 10px solid #eceeef;
    width: 211px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    float: left;
}

.infoBox p {
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-right: 6px;
}

#walkieTalkieOne {
    width: 209px;
    height: 186;
}

#walkieTalkieTwo {
    width: 210px;
    height: 186;
}
#walkieTalkieThree {
    width: 211px;
    height: 186;
}

.infoHeader {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.infoDesc{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.closer {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 50px;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
}

#resellerButton {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
}

#resellButtLink{
    text-decoration: none;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
}
</style>
```

You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/S3523/1/)

Comment: I see the fiddle and it does in fact look the way it should, but when I implement it, there is still no change. The largest the parent div is allowed to expand is 784 pixels. So there is a mainWrapper div that has that width on it as well. Could that be part of the problem? I edited my question with a fiddle of the complete code.

Comment: @user2662333 Yes that could be a problem because of the size of your image and the list. Try reducing the width of .heading to 400px and it should fit nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the element to before the content - otherwise, it's just going to float what comes after it... which is nothing.

Comment: You mean putting the float directly in the img tag?

Comment: No, I mean moving your floated element to be before the content that should flow around it.

Comment: Ah ok. The text shouldn't flow around it. The text should just remain on the left as it is but the image should be on the right and on the same line. I tried moving the element higher up but it just ended up in the middle of the ul content.